# Get variable from url

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble getting a variable from a url. I tried the following 2 urls:

```
http://intranet/generalinfo/campusdirectory/index.php/personnel?page=1
http://intranet/generalinfo/campusdirectory/?page=1
```

I've tried the following, neither of which worked:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
$page = get_query_var('page');
```

I tried adding the following to my functions.php:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
function add_get_val() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('page'); 
}
```

When I click on the link, it takes me to the following url:

```
http://intranet/generalinfo/campusdirectory/page/3/
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: for the very last one you would need `get_query_var`, the values that function take are the same ones used to configure `WP_Query` and are listed in that classes docs on the official WP dev documentation site. Also `$wp->add_query_var('page'); ` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It would also be good to know which parts of the URL are the WP install, which are pages/posts/archives/etc

Answer (score 0):

There were actually 2 issues. First, I had to use get_query_var. Secondly, for some reason Permalinks were set to a weird custom structure. It's working now.